# Edit field in contentType B when creating or editing node of contentType A

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I need to edit a field in contentType B when I create or edit nodes of contentType A.

I know it's possible to use rules for this but I need to have more control so I want to do it in my own module.

Tried this code without success:

```
function MYMODULE_node_presave($node) {
    MYMODULE_change_value($node);
}

function MYMODULE_change_value($node) {
    $node = node_load($node->nid);

    $referenced_nid = $node->referenced_node[LANGUAGE_NOE][0]['target_id']

    $referenced_node = node_load(referenced_nid);

    $referenced_node->my_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 12345.0;
    node_save($referenced_node);
}
```

Am I choosing the wrong hook?

Comment: It's D7 or D8 ?

Comment: Sorry., I always forget. It's D7.

Comment: you use this module [entityreference module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) to reference nodes ?

Comment: Yes. The nodes of contentType B are referenced in nodes of contentType A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave().
 */
function yourModule_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'your_typeA') {
    yourModule_change_value($node);
  }
}

function yourModule_change_value($node) {
  if (isset($node->field_node_referenced[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'])) {
    //- Get referenced node id
    $referenced_node_id = $node->field_node_referenced[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'];
    //- Load referenced node
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $referenced_node_id);
    $wrapper->field_name->set(array(
      'value' => 'test new field value'
    ));
    $wrapper->save();
  }
}
```

Comment: The field that I want to change is a taxonomy term. Using your code, I get this error: EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. Value at node(26)->my_field: array ( 'tid' => 6, ). I changed your line: 'value' => 'test new field value' to 'tid' => 6

Comment: try with `field_name->set(6)` without value

Comment: I was also looking for a solutio and that's exactly what I've found. It depends on the type of value you want to change. Thanks for you support berramou!

Comment: you are welcome!

Comment: I have a related question. I'm passing the $node variable to my "change_value" function. Is it possible to pass also the previous node values?

Comment: how is previous node value? for example you want to create nodeA of typeA which node you would pass  ?

Comment: I can pass all the previous node or a specific field. If it's only a field, it would be the referenced node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84490/discussion-between-zephirus-and-berramou).